# adding all jar files in a folder to the classpath

Tags: gradle

I have tried a number of different approaches but they don't work

```
dependencies {
  reverseEngineer files("${projectDir}/drivers")
}
```

What I want is to add all the *.jar files in the drivers folder to the classpath.  The user may add and remove drivers as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this as your dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'drivers')
```

Comment: The hint to use `fileTree` was perfect. I was stuck like the OP using `files`